# Why do we call the verb in the first sentence in the infinitive form while we don't in the second one?

Tags: infinitives, bare-infinitive

http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/infinitive_form.htm

The sentences were taken from the link above.

1. I must run every day.
2. I run every day.

As far as I know, they both have the verb 'run'. Doesn't that mean the verbs are in their base form?

Comment: You are right -- the lexical verb in both cases is "run". But there's a difference in the form of the verb: in 1. "must" is a modal auxiliary verb and modals take a complement in the form of a bare infinitival clause -- thus "run" is the plain form of "run". In 2. by contrast "run" is the present tense form.

Comment: Almost all verbs have the same form for the infinitive and the first person present simple. 'Be' shows the difference: (1') I must be early today. / (2') I am early today.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this pair:

1. She  must run every day.
2. She  runs every day.

Here  hopefully it is clearer that in sentence 1 the bare infinitive is used (because it follows the modal auxiliary *must*) and in sentence 2 the present tense is used. The regular ending for verbs in the third person singular is  *s*.

The same is true for your pair of sentences. It's just that the forms look  identical. The form of the bare infinitive and the form of all regular 
 simple present tense verbs  are the same–with the exception of the third person singular.

Answer (score 0):

In "I run" and "I must run", the two instances of "run" have the same form, but they are not fulfilling the same role grammatically.  The first is finite and present tense, the second the bare infinitive.

Verbs can be finite or nonfinite.  The finite forms can be inflected according to person or tense:

- "I *run*" -- "she *runs*" (inflection for person).
- "I *run*" -- "I *ran*" (inflection for tense).

The nonfinite forms are the infinitive and the participles.  The nonfinite forms are invariable, taking the same forms in all persons and all tenses.  (This isn't true of all languages.)

- "I am *running*" -- "she is *running*".
- "I am *running*" -- "I was *running*".
- "I have *taken*" -- "she has *taken*".
- "I can *run*" -- "I could *run*".
- "I must *run*" -- "she must *run*".

Similarly, "run" can be a verb in some sentences and a noun in others ("I'm going for a run") - this doesn't mean that nouns and verbs are the same thing.

A finite verb is said to inflect for three persons and two numbers.  In English, the inflections have mostly been lost or levelled, so "run" is used in the 1st person singular ("I run") and in all plural persons ("we run", "you run", "they run") (and "you" is often semantically singular), but "runs" remains as the 3rd person singular.  In the past or preterite, "ran" is used for all persons (only the verb "be" preserves a distinction between persons in the past tense: "was" v "were").

Although the present tense form of the verb is normally (apart from the 3rd person singular) identical to the bare infinitive, there are exceptions.  For example, "am", "are", "is" are used as the present tense forms of "be"; "be" is used as the infinitive (and also as the subjunctive).  Also, modal verbs such as "can" and "must" don't have infinitives (at least in standard English): there is no such thing as "to must" or "I can must" or "I will can".

Comment: I see. I found the explanation very helpful. However, one thing I would like to further question: are modal verbs considered verbs too, in a literal sense (since I remember that modal verbs = "helping" verbs, and therefore cannot stand alone as the main verb in a sentence)? I am quite puzzled about "A finite verb is said to inflect for three persons and two numbers" and how this inflection has been lost in English. Is it correct to assume that in the past, there were different forms of "run" for different numbers of subjects and different forms of "ran" in the aforementioned situation?

Comment: Old English (Anglo-Saxon) verb forms had a significantly more complicated pattern (or set of patterns) of inflection - see http://oldenglish.wikia.com/wiki/Reference_2:_Verbs .  So, for "lufian" (to love), there were four distinct present-tense forms (not counting subjunctive) - the first person singular, second person singular, third person singular, and a shared (non-person-specific) plural form.  The simple past also had four distinct forms.
It is best to consider auxiliary verbs, including modal auxiliaries, as verbs, but obviously, they are a special category of verbs.

Comment: Even in Shakespeare's day a regular verb still had three distinct present-tense forms, such as "love" (1st p.sng. and plural), "lovest" (2nd p.sng.) and "loveth" (3rd p.sng.).  (The 3rd person singular form "loves" also already existed, but I won't count it as a separate form because it has the same grammatical role as "loveth", the distinction being one of dialect, idiolect or sometimes register.)

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation. That cleared all the questions I had. And thanks for taking the time to answer. Good day.